# How to make more than one div appear using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel I am very close to finishing this.  I have a form with an "Add Children" button that when pressed will make a div show.  The form has 15 divs hidden (#child1 - #child15). I have it working to show only the first row (#child1).

My problem is that when the button is pressed again, the next row (#child2, #child3, etc...) should appear and I am not sure how to get it to show.  I tried putting in the counter but I am new to jQuery and any help would be very much appreciated.  I don't expect this to be a difficult issue, just one that is eluding my novice ability.

Here is the jQuery.  If i need to edit or add more code to help the question please let me know.  Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter=0

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {
        $('#child1').show(function() {
        counter++
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a class `children-to-show` to your divs `#child1 - #child15` and write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {
        $('.children-to-show:hidden').first().show();
    });
</script>
```

This way you dont't need a counter and the div id doesnt't have to be in a row, so you have more ways to configure your div ids.

**Explanation**

On every click on `addChildren`, the next hidden element with class `children-to-show` is shown.

**EDIT**

gdoron is right, so if you want to get it work with classes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {
        $('.children-to-show').not('.is-visible').first().show().addClass('is-visible');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Simple and sweet.  Nice answer.

Comment: @lucuma. I'm not getting how does it answer the question.

Comment: @gdoron It looks for the first component with that class by index and shows it, making it not hidden. Next time through the first hidden component is actually the second, but the first one is already shown

Comment: @HunterMcMillen. Ohh, now I got his intention. nice!

Comment: @HunterMcMillen. The only drawback is that `:hidden` can't use the native `querySelectorAll` function. not that big seal though. If you can change the DOM, simply add the previous showed element a class, and select the first without it. BTW `eq()` + counter is a lot faster...

Answer (score 2):

If the `<div>`s are in order 1,2,3,4...15:

```
$('#addChildren').click(function() {        
        $('div[id^="child"]').eq(counter).show();
        counter++;
});
```

If they are not in order:

```
$('#addChildren').click(function() {        
        $('#child' + (++counter)).show();
});
```

Comment: hi mate, doesn't you first code try to catch multiple elements with same id `#child1`?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use for loop if you know exact amount of divs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {

for (i=1; i<=15; i++)
  {
  $('#child'+i).show();
  }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter=1

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {
        $('#child' + counter).show(function() {
        counter++
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

You can add a condition to check the limit of 15 as well. Something like ..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter=1

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addChildren').click(function() {
                if(counter <= 15) {
$('#child' + counter).show(function() {
                counter++
                });
}
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just concatenate the counter variable into the jQuery selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter=0

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {
        $('#child' + counter).show(function() {
        counter++
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the div you're showing a variable like `$('#child' + counter)` so it will show a different div as the values of `counter` get updated.

```
var counter=1

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addChildren').click(function() {
        $('#child' + counter).show(function() {
            counter++
        });
    });
});
```

I've put together this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbQNp/) to show you.